# What is the order of onPostExecute(Result) methods execution?Can i change it?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm implementing quite a simple task - user authorization.All network operations I've implemented via AsyncTask. And I have a problem. I have two AsyncTasks - one it is authorization which calls more low level and common for all network tasks operation (JSON parsing, REST realization etc.) which also is implemented via AsyncTask. And  I have a problem:  onPostExecute methods of these two operations are called in a wrong order.

So the question - can I someway set the order of their execution, or may be you give me some advice how to handle all this in a right way.But don't suggest me to refuse AsyncTask and use something else. I want a right solution with AsyncTask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you have two sequential operations but you are running them asynchronously?

Comment: What do you mean by `onPostExecute methods of these two operations are called in a wrong order.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should have a single `AsyncTask` for the high-level background operation. The low-level network activities should be invoked directly in the high-level `doInBackground`. By having two `AsyncTask`s running, you lose the ability to easily coordinate the timing of their individual work.

If for some reason you need to independently run the lower-level operations in an `AsyncTask` (that is, for purposes other than authorization), then that `AsyncTask` should also directly invoke the low-level network activities from its own `doInBackground`; however, the low-level activities should still be separate from any `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have a question because of the lack of knowledge.You said "however, the low-level activities should still be separate from any AsyncTask" But as far as i know in Android 4.0 any network operation must be implemented in separate thread. Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: @HarryCater - Well, to be honest, upon reading this three months later, I don't know what I meant. The `doInBackground` method of an `AsyncTask` is already running off the UI thread. There's no need to fire up another `AsyncTask` to do networking; the `doInBackground` code can execute the networking operations directly. I think that in the second paragraph I had in mind a case where you might need to run the low-level networking operations without starting the high-level authorization logic. But I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote the last phrase. Sorry about that--just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Run your 2. asycTask in 1. fisrt asycTask onPostExecute method. By the way you can set its order yourself.

like below,

```
 private class task1 extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

     protected int doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         // do your stuf
         return 1;
     }


     protected void onPostExecute(int result) {
           // first task finished and second task starts
           new task2().execute();
     }
 }


private class task2 extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

     protected int doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     // do your stuf
         return 1;
     }


     protected void onPostExecute(int result) {
        // do your stuf
     }
 }
```